# Set Value of EdiTextPreference in android

Tags: android

in Android i want to set EditTextprefernce value i tried

```
EditTextPreference etp = (EditTextPreference)getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("mykey");
etp.setText("123");
```

tell me how can i set EditTextpreference value in program dont suffest me in xml/preference.xml  to write android:default="123" want to do programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
EditTextPreference myEditTextPreference = (EditTextPreference) findPreference("myPrefKey");

    myEditTextPreference
            .setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference,
                        Object newValue) {
                    try {
                        String input = newValue.toString();

                        if (containsOnlyNumbers(input)) {

                            int result = Integer.parseInt(input);
                            if (result < 0) {
                                result = 0;
                            }

                            // Parsing was successful. Use the result..
                            // TODO                             


                        } else {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Invalid value input '" + input
                                    + "', using old one");
                            return false;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        return false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });


    private boolean containsOnlyNumbers(String s) {
        if(s.length()<1) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```